# Performance hit using modules in fortran

Tags: performance, module, fortran, fortran90

I'm converting a F77 code into F90, and i'm trying to get rid of implicit declaration and includes.

In particular, I have a subroutine (frequently called)

the subroutine :

```
  SUBROUTINE GRADE(NIE,NJE,NKE,IDEW,IDNS,IDTB,FI,FIF,GRX,GRY,GRZ)
  USE module_dec
  USE module_geom_common
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL    :: FI(NXYZA),FIF(NXYZA)
  REAL    :: GRX(NXYZA),GRY(NXYZA),GRZ(NXYZA)
  REAL    :: BN(NXYZA),BE(NXYZA),BT(NXYZA)
  REAL    :: FIE
  INTEGER :: NIE,NJE,NKE,IDEW,IDNS,IDTB
  INTEGER :: I,J,K

  ! Declaration of the variables used in file.inc
  REAL    :: ARX,ARY,ARZ
  REAL    :: AKX,AKY,AKZ
  REAL    :: ARE,ARE2,ARKSI2
  REAL    :: FXE,FXW
  INTEGER :: INE
  REAL    :: DELN,DELNR

  DO 30 K=2,NKE
  DO 30 I=2,NIE
  DO 30 J=2,NJE

  INCLUDE "file.inc"

    FIE=FI(INP)*FXW+FI(INE)*FXE
    BE(INP)=  FIE*ARX
    BN(INP)=  FIE*ARY
    BT(INP)=  FIE*ARZ

  30 CONTINUE

  DO 31 K=2,NKE
  DO 31 I=2,NIE
  DO 31 J=2,NJE

    INP=LK(K)+LI(I)+J
    GRX(INP)=GRX(INP)+BE(INP)
    GRY(INP)=GRY(INP)+BN(INP)
    GRZ(INP)=GRZ(INP)+BT(INP)

    GRX(INP+IDEW)=GRX(INP+IDEW)-BE(INP)
    GRY(INP+IDEW)=GRY(INP+IDEW)-BN(INP)
    GRZ(INP+IDEW)=GRZ(INP+IDEW)-BT(INP)

  31 CONTINUE
```

and file.inc

```
  INP=LK(K)+LI(I)+J
  INE=INP+IDEW
  INS=INP-IDNS
  INB=INP-IDTB
  INBS=INB-IDNS

  FXE=FIF(INP)
  FXW=1.-FXE

  DXS=.5*(X(INP)-X(INS)+X(INB)-X(INBS))
  DYS=.5*(Y(INP)-Y(INS)+Y(INB)-Y(INBS))
  DZS=.5*(Z(INP)-Z(INS)+Z(INB)-Z(INBS))

  DXT=.5*(X(INP)-X(INB)+X(INS)-X(INBS))
  DYT=.5*(Y(INP)-Y(INB)+Y(INS)-Y(INBS))
  DZT=.5*(Z(INP)-Z(INB)+Z(INS)-Z(INBS))

  ARX=DYS*DZT-DYT*DZS
  ARY=DZS*DXT-DZT*DXS
  ARZ=DXS*DYT-DXT*DYS

  ARE2=ARX**2+ARY**2+ARZ**2

  AKX=XC(INE)-XC(INP)
  AKY=YC(INE)-YC(INP)
  AKZ=ZC(INE)-ZC(INP)
  ARKSI2=AKX**2+AKY**2+AKZ**2
```

With wich, my program have an execution time of 12s

When I move the declaration of variables present in 'file.inc' in a module,

```
  MODULE module_geom_common
    REAL    :: ARX,ARY,ARZ
    REAL    :: AKX,AKY,AKZ
    REAL    :: ARE,ARE2,ARKSI2
    REAL    :: FXE,FXW
    INTEGER :: INE
    REAL    :: DELN,DELNR
  END MODULE module_geom_common
```

I have now an execution time of 13s.

I'm compiling with ifort, but I observe the same comportment with gfortran.

I don't understand why am I slower.
Is it because the variables declared inside a module will be put elsewere in memory, causing cache miss or something like that ?

Is there a way to overcome this without using include ?

EDIT : I've edited my question in order to give more details.

Comment: Local variables could be allocated on the stack or even registers, whereas module variables are statically allocated. If your code makes any procedure calls, the compiler has to assume that module variables could be accessed or modified, whereas local variables not in argument lists cannot - this can affect optimization. Without seeing a complete example, it's hard to speculate further.

Comment: How are you doing the timing?